# Why Spring documentation is not perfect

Tags: java, spring-mvc

hey i am trying to build simple hello world spring web application using maven.

when i go to url http://localhost:8080/mvc/greeting it give me 404.

here is my pom

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.ilyas.learning.mvcspring</groupId>
<artifactId>mvc</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>mvc</name>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and here is Greeting class

@Controller
public class GreetingController {

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/greeting", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String greeting(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World") String name){
    return "Hello " + name;
}
```

}

and here is Main class.

public class Main extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

```
@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(Main.class);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried without `/mvc`?  Nothing in your code specifies that Spring would deploy to the `/mvc` context at all.

Comment: yes i tried, http://localhost:8080/mvc/ is working fine and printing index.html context.

Comment: Let me guess you expect the message `Hello World!"` to be returned but it doesn't. Ofcourse it won't because it is a `@Controller` then when returning a `String` it assumes it is a name of a view to render. It will resolve to some template or static file (which it cannot find hence the 404). Either add `@ResponseBody` to your method, indicating you want your `String` returned as the body of a response or replace `@Controller` with `@RestController`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are not sending RequestParam value, you need to mark it `required=false`
so your method will

```
public String greeting(@RequestParam(value = "name", required=false, defaultValue = "World") String name){
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to add `@RequestMapping` annotation on before on public class `GreetingController`. you can refer below sample code :

```
@Controller 
@RequestMapping("/mvc")
public class GreetingController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/greeting", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json", consumes = "application/json")
    public String greeting(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World") String name){

 //do things

    }

}
```

if you create rest service then you can try to use `@RestController` at `@Controller`.

Comment: it did not work for me still same issue.

Comment: check your `web.xml` and `ApplicationContext.xml` file is located at proper location or not. and load `ApplicationContext.xml` from `web.xml`. use `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet` to load `ApplicationContext`

Comment: i am not using web.xml infect i am using spring annotations for configuration